# Using Kafka and Spark Streaming for serving a web application

Tags: apache-spark, service, apache-kafka, web, spark-streaming

Let's assume I have a website with a form where user can past some values. Now I want to take these values, process them with Spark Streaming and return the result back to the user. Something like this:

[image]

Detailed setup does not really matter - the Spark Streaming can be doing some recommendation or prediction and could sit on top of Databricks; backend can be a Flask application...

---

My questions are:

1. How to tell the Website Backend server that Spark Streaming processed the input data and output the results somewhere?
2. Which pieces this pipeline misses? Some intermediate DB such as Redis/Mongo/SQL? Some message broker such as Kafka?

I can't get my head around the part where the Spark Streaming sends info back to the Website backend. If I send the result of Spark Streaming processing to database (Mongo, Redis, MySQL), filesystem (S3, Blob, HDFS) or message broker (Kafka, Kinesis), how to tell the Website backend about it?

Comment: You can look into Apache Livy for a REST API for Spark

Answer (score 3):

You approach a solution based on a Event Driven Architecture. In my mind I would have the following components:

1. **Website backend**. This service is the one connected to Apache Kafka for Producing and Consuming events. It will receive all the events from the UI and then will publish into Kafka topics the events triggered by the UI. You can create one Topic per each type of event. in order to have the events categorized. On the other hand, it will also have the role of Consumer (listener), which will be reading the messages from the different topics where the answers coming from Apache Spark will be published into Kafka.
2. **Apache Kafka**. This is the component which is missing in the picture right know. It will play the role of passing messages to the different components which are subscribed to the topics. Make sure you have all the events categorized in different Topics.
3. **Spark Streaming**. This component will be listening to Kafka for some events. Depending on what event you are getting, you will probably want to process the event differently. Once you process the event with Apache Spark, you will send the output to Apache Kafka.

Essentially, using Apache Kafka for event driven architecture would be good based on what your need. If you want to go deeper in services architecture with Apache Kafka, please check [this out](https://es.slideshare.net/ConfluentInc/microservices-in-the-apache-kafka-ecosystem#).

If you want add one more level of storage as Casandra to store the results of the prediction is really up to you, in my opinion will be a good idea, in that way you do not need to trigger Spark jobs for events which were already processed previously.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have another question - how do you keep the user session in this event driven architecture? That is, user XYZ sends data to backend -> Kafka -> Spark -> Kafka and now backend will consume the results and must somehow determine that it is result for user XYZ. Do I have to keep the session_id all the way through the pipeline?

Comment: Well,it will depends on what your needs are. For example, if Spark will be in a cluster with Kerberos and you want the jobs to be triggered using the same 'user login id', you will need a special user which will be able to run jobs in the cluster on behalf of the 'user login id'.

Comment: You will be handling sessions as any other web app. The backend service though, must provide the correct certificates to connect to Kafka. Then you can handle access to certain actions based on the user privilegies.

Comment: Security is a whole different thing from the original question  though :)

Comment: Some points that don't sound ok for me: 1) Kafka streaming is work on streaming data, no to read a value and do some spark. 2) If you send request through kafka, the website backend will read all the responses generated for all the users. 3) Spark scales on data, not on resources. I mean, you are going to have big issues if you need to run a significant number of spark jobs per hour